# Task List<T> apresentando erro Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, lista, xamarin-forms, task

Estou criando uma Task List<> porem a mesma apresenta erro no 'TModel'
Erro apresentado:   O nome do tipo ou do namespace "TModel" não pode ser encontrado (está fantando uma diretiva using ou uma referencia de assembly?)

```
public async Task<List<TModel>>MetodoPostTeste(string RouteCommand, params object[] args)
    {
        var ModelType = typeof(TModel);//take the class
        var ModelTypeName = ModelType.Name;//take the class name
        var ModelWorldLength = "_lib".Length;//takes the size of the class name up to _lib

        //subtracts from the name of the class the _lib, thus being able to specify the route for the post
        var ModelTypeNameRoute = $"{ModelTypeName.Substring(0, ModelTypeName.Length - ModelWorldLength)}";


        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_commom.GetBaseUrl());
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"api/{ModelTypeNameRoute}/{RouteCommand}");

        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(""), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        var x = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        List<TModel> ret = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TModel>>(x.Result);

        return ret;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sim, o Generic tipo T é o TModel

Comment: Quando passo o mouse em cima de List<TModel> ele informa  T is TModel

Comment: era isso mesmo, ja consegui usar aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme mencionei nos comentários, se você pretende usar o generics, a declaração do método está errada, faltou justamente a especificação do tipo genérico.

Mude assinatura para o seguinte que deve resolver:

```
public async Task<List<TModel>>MetodoPostTeste<TModel>(string RouteCommand, params object[] args)
{
    ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.